# Cómo verificar si un dato existe en base de datos PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy intentando hacer un registro con pdo, necesito que se haga una consulta a la base de datos y si es que el correo que ingresó el usuario no existe en la base de datos se cree el usuario, si es que existe que le diga que cambie de correo. Primero cree la consulta, luego use el objeto conexion con prepare, luego la ejecuté y en un array le pasé el parámetro, luego entonces creo que hay que recorrerlo con fetch, pero apartir de ahí me pierdo. Supongo que hay que saber si fetch encontró un dato igual y si es así hacer un if, pero la verdad no entiendo bien en las webs que he leído. muchas gracias. Solo bastaría con la explicación de la consulta, ingresar los datos sí se como se hace.

```js
<?php
include "conexion.php";
$nombre=$_POST['nombres'];
$apellido=$_POST['apellidos'];
$correo=$_POST['correo'];
$pass=$_POST['contraseña'];
$pass_cifrado=password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email=?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($correo));

if($registro=$stm->fetch()>0){
echo "ya exite el registro";
}else{
    echo "no exite el registro";
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Estoy usando una conexion PDO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para evaluar si un registro ya existe, puedes proceder de esta forma:

- Modifica tu consulta, para que en lugar de hacer una selección de todos las filas, hagas un `COUNT` de las mismas pero donde el `email` coincida con el valor enviado
- Usaremos la función [`fetchColumn`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) para obtener el número de filas que la consulta generó
- Evalúas dentro del condicional la variable donde almacenaste el número de filas

  - Si dicha variable es mayor a 0 entonces el registro ya existe
  - Si no, entonces el email no existe y puedes proceder con el alta

Entonces tu consulta:

```
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuario WHERE email= ?");
$stmt->execute(array($correo));

$emailExistencia = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if ($emailExistencia > 0) {
    echo "El email: {$correo} ya existe prueba con otro";
} else {
    /*
        Aquí procede tu alta
    */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo que puedes hacer es usar la función **`rowCount ()`**  con ello el el if podrías colocar si la consulta ejecutada te ha devuelto un valor.

```
if($stmt->rowCount ()==1)
```

Comment: Voy a dar un voto en contra a tu respuesta, porque no se debería confiar en `rowCount()` para saber el número de filas de una tabla. [El Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php) es clarísimo en ese punto: *«PDOStatement::rowCount() devuelve el número de filas afectadas por la última sentencia DELETE, INSERT, o UPDATE ejecutada por el correspondiente objeto PDOStatement.»* Realmente `rowCount()` existe para consultas del tipo `DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE`, no para consultas del tipo `SELECT`.

Comment: Además, el Manual dice esto: *«Si la última sentencia SQL ejecutada por el objeto PDOStatement asociado fue una sentencia SELECT, algunas bases de datos podrían devolver el número de filas devuelto por dicha sentencia. Sin embargo, **este comportamiento no está garantizado para todas las bases de datos y no debería confiarse en él para aplicaciones portables**.»*. Lo más seguro para saber la cantidad de filas es `COUNT(*)`, como apunta @BetaM en su respuesta. Esto viene advertido con toda claridad en [phpdelusions](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#count), la mejor guía de PDO que conozco.

Comment: Gracias por el dato, lo tomaré en cuenta y disculpen mi error.

Answer (score -1):

Es tan simple como tomar el email del formulario y validarlo en la base de datos de la siguiente manera.

```
$email = $_post['email'];
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT email FROM usuario WHERE email= $email");

if ($email === $query) {
  echo "El email existe";
} else {
  #:: Sentencia para registrar el usuario.
}
```