# ¿Cómo verificar la existencia de un usuario en MySQL con PDO-PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

esta es mi primera pregunta acá en Stack Overflow. Estoy empezando a aprender desarrollo web y quiero hacer un mini proyecto personal, una página web con PHP que funcione con MySQL y PDO (sin ponerle tanto cuidado a su aspecto, solo tratando de que sea funcional).

Mi problema aparece cuando quiero verificar que un usuario con cierta key exista dentro de mi tabla, he probado con varias soluciones a problemas similares que he encontrado en internet (incluyendo algunas de StackOverflow) pero ninguna me ha funcionado, al realizar `var_dump` al rowcount veo que siempre tiene valor de 0, aunque el key que yo quiero que valide realmente exista o no en la base de datos.

Muestra de la estructura y datos de mi tabla
[image: Muestra de la estructura y datos de mi tabla]

Códigos que no me funcionaron:

```php
function existe($id,$cnx){
        
        $consulta = $cnx->prepare("SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE 
        codigo=:codigo");
        $consulta ->bindParam (":codigo", $id);
            
        if($consulta->rowcount() == 0){
            echo "No existe";
        }else 
            echo "Existe";
    
        var_dump($consulta->rowcount());
        die();
            
        
 }
```

Resultado al intentar validar la existencia del registro (con código original)

[image: Resultado al intentar validar la existencia del registro (con código original)]

Código sugerido (1), la función sigue sin funcionar ya que aunque el dato que busco exista o no, la función siempre devuelve un resultado negativo luego de realizar la búsqueda.

```php
function existe($id,$cnx){
    
    $consulta = $cnx->prepare("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM empleados WHERE codigo= ?");
    $consulta->execute(array($id));

    $columnasAfectadas = $consulta->fetchColumn();

    if($columnasAfectadas == 0){
        echo "No existe";
    }else 
        echo "Existe";
    var_dump($columnasAfectadas);
    die();
    
}
```

Resultado al intentar validar la existencia del registro (con código actualizado debido a la sugerencia)

[image: Resultado al intentar validar la existencia del registro (con código actualizado debido a la sugerencia)]

**Código final (no usa el la función COUNT)**

Luego de intentar sin éxito, y pese a las recomendaciones, que la función funcionara usando COUNT, decidí tomar aire de esto y se me ocurrió hacer una simple consulta cualquiera y luego de ahí validar el resultado de la búsqueda.

```php
function existe($id,$cnx){    
    $consulta = $cnx->prepare("SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE codigo = :codigo");        
    $consulta->execute(array('codigo' => $id));    
    $resultado =$consulta->fetchAll();    
    return $resultado != NULL;       
}
```

Supongo que estaba embotado y por eso no pude pensar en una solución tan fácil en su momento, gracias a los que estuvieron interesados en ayudarme, por ahora me daré por vencido con eso del COUNT, pero puede que luego me haga falta entender por qué fallé al usarlo en este caso.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cómo verificar si un dato existe en base de datos PDO?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/387784/c%c3%b3mo-verificar-si-un-dato-existe-en-base-de-datos-pdo)

Comment: No, acabo de adaptar la respuesta ahí dada a mi problema pero no me funciona tampoco.

Comment: Así es, a la hora de llamar a la función, le entrego el parámetro usando el $_GET

Answer (score 1):

Prueba así:

```
function existe($id,$cnx){
    $consulta = $cnx->prepare("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM empleados WHERE codigo = :codigo");
    $consulta ->bindParam (":codigo", $id);
    $consulta->execute()//agrega esta línea
    if($consulta->fetchColumn() > 0){
        echo " Si existe";
    }else {
        echo "No existe";
   } 
 }
```

Estoy desde mi celular, por lo que probablemente haya errores

Comment: Tienes razón, me ha faltado el `Count`

Comment: Hola Franqo, tu código tampoco me funcionó, por algún motivo que desconozco. Pero afortunadamente logré llegar a la solución. Gracias por tu interés en ayudarme, igualmente hacia ti, @BetaM. Que tengan un muy buen día. Ya podré cerrar mis 20 pestañas abiertas por fin jejeje

Comment: @BetaM Desconocía que se podía hacer tal cosa hasta que lo dijiste, gracias por el dato. Ya publiqué mi respuesta y en cuanto pueda (2 días), la aceptaré como solución para el problema.

Comment: Recuerda añadir tu respuesta para posibles futuras preguntas semejantes :)

Answer (score -2):

Esta función sí logra su cometido de una forma tan sencilla que puede incluso parecer absurdo el no pensar en ella desde un principio

```php
function existe($id,$cnx){    
    $consulta = $cnx->prepare("SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE codigo = :codigo");  //preparas la consulta del elemento cuya existencia deseas validar   
    $consulta->execute(array('codigo' => $id));                                   //ejecutas las consulta, enviándole el parámetro externo de una forma segura para evitar inyección SQL
    $resultado =$consulta->fetchAll();                                            //colocas el resultado de tu búsqueda dentro de la variable resultado, almacenada en un array
    return $resultado != NULL;                                                    //si resultado es null, significa que no existe ninguna entrada coincidente con tus parámetros de búsqueda, si el array no es null, entonces sí hay por lo menos una entrada que coincida con tus parámetros de búsqueda

//se retorna true el resultado de la verificación es exitoso, en caso contrario se retorna else
}
```

Comment: Doy -1 a esta respuesta, porque este no sería el código adecuado para verificar que un registro existe. Esto podría ser óptimo en caso de querer verificar por una lado si el registro existe **y al mismo tiempo necesitar los datos**. En cambio, si no necesitas los datos lo mejor es ejecutar un `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM empleados WHERE codigo = :codigo`, luego obtener el total de filas encontradas con `fetchColumn()` y comparar. La cuestión aquí es que estarías trayendo todas las columnas de la tabla **para no usarlas**, y eso desde el punto de vista de la optimización no es correcto.