# No me valida si hay un dato en la base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Envio a traves de la funcion el dato a revisar por la verificacion ajax pero al recibir devuelta este no pasa por el e.preventDefault(); pasa de largo, creo que tengo un problema de sintaxis

Adjunto el JavaScript y abajo adjunto el PHP

```
 function requestValidation(done) {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'validateAlias.php',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { alias: $('input[name=alias]').val().trim() },
          success: function(res) { done(null, JSON.parse(res).isValid) },
          error: function(err) { done(err) }
        });
      }
    
    
  $('input[name=alias]').blur(function() {
    requestValidation(function(err, isValid) {
      if (err) console.error(err);
      if (isValid) console.log("Alias no existe");
      else {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("existe el alias");
      }
    });
```

En el PHP estoy trabajando con postgreSql

```
<?php
sleep(1);
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
];

$conn = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=fhernandez;host=localhost","postgres","monotono11",$options);

if($_REQUEST) {
    $alias = $_REQUEST['alias'];
    $sql="Select * from voto where alias = '$alias'";
    $result=pg_query($conn,$sql)

    $result= $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($result);
  
  



?>
```

Como pueden ver no se si estoy mandando mal el JSON o que las validaciones o el fetch esta mal, si me pueden aclarar la duda se les agradeceria, soy nuevo usando esta herramienta

Comment: Abre la consola de tu navegador y checa estas 2 pestañas: console para ver si obtienes algún error y network para verificar si los datos de tu formulario están viajando a tu backend y nos comentas

Comment: Aunado a eso verifica si esto te sirve [en tu backend](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/387784/c%c3%b3mo-verificar-si-un-dato-existe-en-base-de-datos-pdo/387789#387789), por otro lado ya que usas PDO, entonces es mejor usar consultas preparadas

Comment: no hay ningun error en network, en el tema de de PDO, la primera vez que lo intente sin PDO no me funciono, y vi en un blog el PDO y me funciono y me quede con eso

Comment: La recomendación que te hago de consultas preparadas es usando precisamente PDO (*aunque no es estrictamente relevante a la pregunta aqui es una observación*): https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php, en network lo que debes verificar es si la data si viaja

Comment: tienes razon, no viaja  y no tengo ni idea por que no llega al php en la consulta, deberia viajar a validateAlias.php pero no viaja segun la network

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estás imprimiendo la estructura del arreglo y no el arreglo en sí, prueba lo siguiente solo para tu línea de conexión y captura del resultado:

```
<?php
$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
];

$pdo = new \PDO(
    'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=fhernandez;charset=utf8',
    'postgres',
    'monotono11',
    $options
);

 $alias = $_REQUEST['alias'];
$stmt = $pdo->query("Select * from voto where alias = '$alias'");
$resultado = $stmt->fetch();

echo $resultado;

?>
```

Comment: sigue pasando de largo con el else{ e.prevenDefault}